# Computation Tree Logic and its Temporal Opeators

Tags: logic, temporal-logic

I've got some questions about the [temporal operators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computation_tree_logic#Temporal_operators) in computation tree logic:

1. Does the **F**`inally` path-specific quantifier `Fq` mean that `q` has to hold in a *subsequent* state or is it also fulfilled when `q` holds in the *current* state?
2. Please consider the following example:

   [image]

   What exactly is specified here? Does it mean: If `q AND r` holds on a path `P` in a graph `G` then `q` has to hold somewhere on the subsequent path of `P`.
   Or does it mean: ... `q` has to hold somewhere on the subsequent path of **every path of `G`**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, a small comment - the $F$ operator comes from the word "future", rather than "finally", although it is indeed very tempting to say "finally".

1. The semantics of $Fq$ with respect to a computation $\pi$ is:
   $$\pi\models Fq \iff \exists i\ge 0, \pi^i \models q$$
   Thus, the 0th suffix is also considered, so if $q$ hold immediately, the formula is still satisfied.
   Observe that you can capture the notion of "strict future" with the formula $XFq$.
2. The formula states that along *every* path ($A$), *every state* $s$ satisfies ($G$) the following: if $q$ and $r$ are true in $s$, then in *every path* starting from $s$, $q$ eventually appears.

I think this is what you meant in your second option.

Comment: That was exactly what I meant in my second question. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

*For the first question:*
Yes. For a specific path, $Fq$ is evaluated to be true if and only if $q$ is satisfied eventually in the future. It includes the case in which $q$ is satisfied immediately in the first state (of the path).

*For the second question:*
First, do you mean $AG(q \land r) \Rightarrow AF(q)$?

Whatever, $G$ here is not a graph. It is another temporal modality in Computation Logic Tree (CTL). $Gq$ is evaluated to be true if and only if $q$ holds from now on forever. $AG (q \land r)$ is pronounced "**invariantly** $q \land r$", meaning that along *all* paths that start in some specified state, $q \land r$ *always* holds. $AF (q)$ pronounced "$q$ is **inevitable**", meaning that along *all* paths that start in some specified state, $q$       *eventually* holds. Informally, "invariantly" implies "inevitable". Thus, we can conclude that $AG(q \land r) \Rightarrow AF(q)$ for some specified state.

Comment: I think the order of parenthesis in the OP's formula is different. It is not $AG(q\wedge r)\implies AFq$, but $AG((q\wedge r)\implies AF(q))$.